# What reason to use on "this doesn't work" questions with obviously valid code?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I've seen several questions with 2-3 lines of code, that ask about why some obvious feature of language doesn't work, while code in question is perfectly valid and can be easily checked by, say just pasting it to console in case of JS (see this question for example: [How to pass a variable in array index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811018/how-to-pass-a-variable-in-array-index)).

The only valid answer to those questions is "No, it works perfectly" and, IMO, those are useless to future visitor, since they don't even represent OP's misunderstanding, that could be shared by other visitors, who'd benefit from explanation, but really is just some kind of pilot or environment error (user tried to run different source? forgot to save before running test? whatever else having zero relation to code itself?)

What reason should be used to close such a questions? I choose "not constructive" for now, for the reason that questions with the single answer that basically means "you're just mistaken" cannot be constructive.

Comment: "Too localized" would fit the bill I think.